# dumping parameters from c++ node

Tags: ros, yaml, ros-kinetic, rosparam, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a simple question but I can't seem to find a nice solution.

My problem is the following:

I have a YAML file that stores some parameters. These parameters are loaded into the parameter server at execution time. For some reason I want to change some parameters and store them permanently in the YAML file.

That is, I retrieve a certain field of the parameter:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue param;
nh.getParam("param_name", param);
ROS_ASSERT(param.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct);
std::string field = static_cast<std::string>(param["field]);
```

and then, after modifying it, I'd like not only to set the new value in the parameter server but also to permanently store this change.

I have seen that [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam) has the `dump` option and I was wondering if there is an analogous function in roscpp. I'd be very glad if someone could show me how it can be done.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327491/dumping-parameters-from-c++-node/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-02**:
I do not believe there is a C++ equivalent to `rosparam dump`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that with the tool I am working on -> https://github.com/asherikov/ariles, a slightly dated version is available as a package in melodic.

---

Originally posted by [asherikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/54069/asherikov/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-27**:
Could you please expand a little on your answer? It's not apparent from the readme of that repository how this could be used to achieve what the OP describes.

**Comment by [asherikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/54069/asherikov/) on 2020-12-17**:
Think of it as a serializer that supports ROS parameter server:

1. define a class with parameters
2. deserialize it from parameter server
3. modify
4. serialize to a yaml file